# ticker in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [marquee text in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android)

can we have ticker in android

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a follow up to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179283/ticker-in-android

In your xml-layout file, add this to your `TextView`

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
```

and in your code:

```
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setSelected(true);
```

why this is needed: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5364

Comment: i have done it but when i move cursor from that textview to other widget like bnutton or any other widget ,the text in the textview will not move like ticker

Comment: can anybody have solution for this problem of ticker in android