# How to make a rolling news banner on android?

Tags: java, android, xml-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [marquee text in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android)

in my app i want to have a news banner with the words moving to one side like tv .. i don't really know how to run that kind of animation .. and should the banner be a TextView ? i'm not really sure of anything .. so i just need the xml format of such thing, Thankss!

Comment: Marquee is possible in android.[Look at this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is commonly referred to as a ticker or marquee. Here's [a tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/google-android-tutorial?page=0,3) on how to make one.

**Edit**: Here's [another tutorial](http://apachejava.blogspot.com/2011/03/marquee-textview-android-ticker.html).

**Edit**: Here's [another stackoverflow question about the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185174/ticker-in-android).

**Edit**: And [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android).