# Marquee TextView on App Widget

Tags: android, textview, marquee, android-appwidget

I am developing an `AppWidget` where I need a `TextView` to display text as a marquee. I have tried using the following code (as one would do in a regular `Activity`), but the text does not scroll.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="150dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" />
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: it's work well in Activity, but can't work in widget, have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 4):

You required to add the following properties in xml for marquee:

```
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

The marquee will appear when the content of the Textview should be larger than width.Make sure  the input occupies the greater space than width.

Comment: On an `AppWidget` the text simply does not scroll despite there being more text than can fit on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The text will only scroll if the `TextView` is either in the selected or focused state and, as Praveen indicates, the text is wider than the available width of the `TextView`. I have not experimented with getting a `TextView` in the selected or focused states in an app widget. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/android-is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsizemarquee-always-scroll) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android) previous StackOverflow answers will give you some things to try.