# Android: calculating view size inside MyAdapter::getView

Tags: listview, layout, android

I have a `ListView` inside which I dynamicaly fill the list items in the `getView()` method, with a combination of `TextView`, and an `ImageView`.

I need to calculate the size of the Text and Image view inside the getView, so I will be able to set `visibility=gone`, if View is too big. I am tring:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ..
  View listItem=view.findViewById(R.id.listItem);
  ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.myImg);
  TextView textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mytxt);
  if (imageView.getRight()>listItemText.getRight()) {
    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
  }
  if (textView.getRight()>listItemText.getRight()) {
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
  }
  ..
}
```

However since I'm inside the `getView()`, the values of layout are not yet created, so I get false values for the `View.getRight()` call.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you decide that according to the length of the String you ar going to put inside the TextView?

Comment: because the same text length may have diffrent actual width

Comment: How about calculating the entire width and subtract width of listItemtext. If your textview adn image view content is small enough for that particular width. Display it or hide it. Just a curious question cant you ellipsize the text and scale the image down so that its always displayed?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do such thing, you can register a `onLayoutChangeListener` and listen for changes in layout parameters, like left, right, top, and down.

```
textView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                // TODO: Take care of visibility here. You can access the parent View by v.getParent() method.
            }
        });
```

But you are not supposed to do such thing in the `getView` method. You can make the textView multiline, or set `android:ellipsize="marquee"` on the textView's layout. More on marquee:
[Marquee text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android)