# Text runs into Button

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have the following XML layout for an item that I put in my list view:

```
 <RelativeLayout·
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:padding="4dp"
 >

   <TextView·
     android:id="@+id/librarySongName"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:ellipsize="marquee"
     android:scrollHorizontally="true"
     android:lines="1"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   />

   <TextView·
     android:id="@+id/libraryArtistName"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
     android:layout_below="@id/librarySongName"
     android:paddingLeft="4dp"
   />

   <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/lib_add_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:minHeight="40dp"
     android:minWidth="40dp"
     android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
   />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

However, when I get I get song titles that are too long, my views end up looking like this:

[image: Picture of list view]

As you can see there are song titles that just get cutoff rather than being ellipsized correctly. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: @run Umm...I did that. It's in the code I posted.

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum what u want marqee to repeat or either as search... as end

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum really sorry i didn't check that..

Comment: may work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2182676/1027463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <TextView·
         android:id="@+id/librarySongName"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lib_add_button"
         android:ellipsize="marquee"
         android:scrollHorizontally="true"
         android:lines="1" gravity="left" 
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       />
```

here you add `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lib_add_button"` and `gravity="left"`

Answer (score 0):

Set the Padding of the textview librarySongName as :

```
 android:paddingRight="25dip"
```

Answer (score 0):

give `weight` or `fixed width` for TextView and Image Button rather than saying wrap_content... because when you say weight both views take some fixed width.. but when you say wrap_content they take as much space as they want to wrap their content...

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:padding="4dp"
 >

   <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/lib_add_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:minHeight="40dp"
     android:minWidth="40dp"
     android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
   />

   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/lib_add_button"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView
       android:id="@+id/librarySongName"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:ellipsize="marquee"
       android:scrollHorizontally="true"
       android:lines="1"
     />

     <TextView
       android:id="@+id/libraryArtistName"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
       android:paddingLeft="4dp"
     />
   </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I wrapped the `TextView`s in a `LinearLayout` and made it fill the area from the left to the `ImageButton` at the right.