# how to apply marquee in android for string

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement marquee a style to print string in android. I'm able to to it with static data but for dynamic it isn't displaying the marquee style.

When I print:

```
String st="this is test application testing for marquee"
```

I get the marquee style.

However, after parsing when I'm getting data:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/twxmorq"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" />
```

I run:

```
myString = myString + "| "+ json_data.getString("news_title").toString();

txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.twxmorq);
txt1.setText(myString1);
```

and I *don't* get the marquee style when I print `mystring`.

Please help me.

**Summary**: For the string ' ST ' I'm getting a marquee style printed string but for `mystring1` I am not getting marequee style.

Comment: @TomR Sorry, I accidentally rejected your edit. Apparently if you say "Improve" in the review interface, then cancel, the edit is rejected and you can't undo that or check it. Sorry. However, if you're going to edit for grammar and readability, please try to be more comprehensive, not just make a few changes here and there.

Comment: is this your need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android

Comment: Why Cant You Search Even in Google..??

Comment: Thanx  jenuine i got solution i was missing one line Thanx

Comment: where is myString1 initialize

Comment: Shalini  can u plz tell me how continue  moving string when useother function of application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for that.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/twxmorq"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    ndroid:lines="1"
    android:textColor="#FF0000" 
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"/>
```

Java Code:-

```
myString = myString + "| "+ json_data.getString("news_title").toString();

txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.twxmorq);
txt1.setSelected(true);
txt1.setText(myString1);
```

Comment: i got but there is one Problem that i dont want to stop the moving string when i m using other function of application can u plz tell me how i can implement this

Comment: @user1594725 sorry i don't know about this.

Comment: what's the purpose of setSelected() here... for me it's working without this.