# Marquee type text in canvas

Tags: android

I'm using `Canvas.drawText` which doesn't have any parameters for that. I have limited width where to draw text in canvas so any ideas how to make it scroll ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [Marquee text in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android)

Comment: Problem here is that, I have custom edit text and I would need to draw marquee type text under that in onDraw method. It is to indicate validation error, it works ok now, but with long text, the text should scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution, I calculate edit text width and measure the text. If text is too wide, then start runnable cycle which adjusts offset x value which is used in drawText parameter.

Comment: can you provide the code for that??.. I am having the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example:

```
public class TextViewMarquee extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv);  
        tv.setSelected(true);  // Set focus to the textview
    }
}
```

The xml file with the textview:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mywidget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textColor="#ff4500"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note**-this works only if android:singleLine="true" is provided..
**Refered** [Marquee text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android)

Comment: Problem here is that, I have custom edit text and I would need to draw marquee type text under that in onDraw method.