# How to show full text value in gridview android

Tags: android, gridview

I bind the data in gridview in android. but the text not shown in fully. Some letters are hide inside. How to show the full text in android gridview. I got like this.

Loan Amount 100 10000000 10000, this value only I bind the gridview. but the value of Loan Amount should show only Loan Am other words are hide and 10 million value also same like this. I used Relative Layout.

This is my full layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/Input_lblcomp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="350dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textSize="14pt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/Input_state" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/Input_propslno" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_pdt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_cust" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_lntype" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_unit" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView8"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="15sp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:minWidth="10dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:textAlignment="inherit" >

</GridView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_gd_factor" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText4"
    android:text="@string/txt_gd_prop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
    android:text="@string/txt_gd_maxlmt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="@string/txt_gd_minlmt" />
```

Comment: post the problem snap if you can!

Comment: can you pur Screenshot, what you want?

Comment: sorry, i can't upload my screenshot here. There is some validation here. what should i do?..

Comment: Post a screenshot for us to get an idea of how it looks right now.

Comment: May be You can use `AutoResizeTextView`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

For more detail check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsize-marquee-always-scroll) too.

I hope this will help you.