# I can't get the marquee effect in Android even after trying all things

Tags: android, marquee

```
public class Crunk extends Activity {
    TextView textView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crunk);
        Button button = null;

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("It's Clicked", "Don't Worry");
                textView.setText("SeeMe");
                textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);

            }
        });
        textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setSelected(true);
        textView.setText("Waitin'....");
    }
```

This code just shows the text not the marquee effect.

Help me out getting the effect.

I want the text to show the effect when the button is tapped.

Still can't get the desired effect even though tried most of the things....

```
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:text="@string/TapMe" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/SeeMe"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: Did you put  android:ellipsize="marquee" in xml to TextView ? See this is working code : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3598855/1405983

Comment: There won't be a marquee effect if the text fits the textview.

Comment: As suggested, you should post the XML of your layout, in order to enable people to help you.

Comment: Found the silly mistake guys...Thanks to all for quick response!!

Comment: You can accept or upvote if its useful to you. @C0d34M3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code in your `onClick()` of **Button**:

```
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("It's Clicked", "Don't Worry");

            textView.setText("Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long ");
            textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            textView.setSelected(true);
            textView.setSingleLine(true);
        }
    });
```

as you have set in `textView.setText("SeeMe");` is small text then `textView's` width.

Comment: You can accept answer dude, if it is useful @C0d34M3

Answer (score 1):

You can set these properties in your layout.xml

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set all the require three things (`ellipsize, selected, and singleLine`):

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.someTextView);
tv.setSelected(true);
tv.setText("Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long ");       
tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
tv.setSingleLine(true):
```

Comment: Roger that man!!Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Does your `TextView` `R.id.textView1` has this property ?

> android:singleLine="true"

Answer (score 0):

Add to textview xml property......

```
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
```