# Android word wrapping textview

Tags: android, textview

Hi I am developing small android application in which I am displaying simple text view. In text view if I am entering large word and if it is not fitting into that line; it will start at new line.But I want to start that word on same.My code looks like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/policyTv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="policy_no"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/policyValTv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=": dfsdlfnsdlfndlnlnfjdnlkdnnvdlnvldnvnflvnflsnvvmsfnlnvfnvjnmvjlsvnjlsf"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
 // output of above code looks like 
   polycy_no :
       dfsdlfnsdlfndlnlnfjdnlkdnnvdlnvldnvnflvnflsnvvmsfnlnvfnvjnmvjlsvnjlsf
 //Instead of that I am expecting 
 polycy_no : dfsdlfnsdlfndlnlnfjdnlkdnnvdlnvldnvnflvnflsnvvmsfncccscs
```

Is this possible? Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: you need to use the word format in android for the expected output.

Comment: But, I don't understand: is there enough space for what you are expecting (all text in the same row)? If yes, simply use `android:lines="1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your standard space with \u00A0 inside Java String or &#160; in your layout or resource files. This is the UTF-8 char that represent a non breaking space.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 android:singleLine="true"
```

and use this also if you have to show **...** in the text

```
 android:ellipsize="end"
```

> android:lines="1" will not help you i have tried that in your condition.

and if you want to show the whole text in one line then you can use Marqquee
for reference check below link

[Marquee text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android)

Comment: If I use `android:singleLine="true"` then it will contain only one line. But I need multi line result as well