# android - Scrolling TextView in each RecyclerView element as needed

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView (`ytRC`) and within that RecyclerView, each element has a thumbnail and a corresponding title that gets inside the RecyclerView via an adapter (`ResultsAdapter`), which puts the thumbnail and the title into a cardview. I want to make my title in the cardview a single line, which is easy enough. But, some titles are too long, so they get cut off. I thought that a marquee textview would be a great way to fix this, so off I went searching for a solution.

I found some results such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android). But, those solutions only partially worked, which means that only 1 out of the 50 elements in the RecyclerView actually scrolled that needed to scroll due to their length. I think this happened because I was calling `title.setEnabled(true);` and `title.requestFocus();` in the `onBindViewHolder()` method of the `ResultsAdapter` and the text was only being marqueed when the only a certain view in the RecyclerView was being produced.

Another solution that I wanted to try was to create a custom TextView class `ScrollingTextView`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;


public class ScrollingTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {
public ScrollingTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    //set scrolling
    setSelected(true);
    requestFocus();
}
}
```

But, using that class yields the same results. So, how would I go about marqueeing a textview in each RecyclerView element that has too much text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marquee is simple for scrolling long textView

```
<TextView
   android:text="lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00"
   android:id="@+id/TextView02"
   android:layout_width="200dip"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
   android:ellipsize="marquee"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:inputType="text"
   android:maxLines="1">
</TextView>
```

And in Program

```
holder.textView.setSelected(true);
```

This will aoutomatically scroll the long the text in TextView.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I don't know why the other answers didn't do me justice. Anyways, the `inputType` attribute you included in actually not needed and the scrolling works just fine without it!

Comment: yep, before 2 years