# How to align icons and display texts as marquee in nested Linear and Relative layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

**My questions :**

1. How can i align the layout as shown below
2. How can i recieve text in a textview with animation similar of marquee text (in place of Welcome Back,John Doe) which scrolls from right to left

**Objective**

[image]

but I am unable to align the icons here, and this is what i am getting:**Screenshot_2**

[image]

**Concept :**

These are icons and will display numbers in red circle whenever there's a notification or a message is recieved.

On the right side , I want to display text which depends the text recieved as message or text in the form of notification.Conside it dynamic, which keeps changing frequently.

I am stucked on this part and unable to solve it. I will be thankful if anyone can help me out with this !! 
Thanks

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_landing_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
    tools:context="com.thebitshoes.uocn.AdminHome"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.66"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/admin_bg_pic"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.22" />
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#737D8C">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#3c424c"
            android:layout_weight="0.31">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/message_icon_new"
                android:id="@+id/message_icon"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/notification_icon"
                android:id="@+id/notification_icon"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Welcome Back, John Doe !"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"

                android:textSize="18sp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.34"
        >


    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: not sure why it got downvoted :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_landing_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.66"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.22"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#737D8C"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:background="#3c424c"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/message_icon"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/add_event" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/notification_icon"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/add_notice" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:background="#3c424c"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Welcome Back, John Doe !"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.34" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Maitri , your suggestion helped :) !!

Answer (score 0):

For marquee code you can look to the [Marquee text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android)

and i don't sure but if you make your textview width match parent it should be okay but i am not 100% sure about it.

Comment: Thanks for the Marquee resource !! was looking for this .