# How to make vertical scrolling textview's in Android

Tags: android

I have been looking for a post to create vertical scrolling multiple textviews. similar to one shown here http://vertical-scroller.vbarsan.com/

But all post are related to creating horizontal scrolling (Marquee) textview.

Comment: put the text inside textview and make the textview scrollable...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Marquee text in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android)

Comment: do you mean text inside textView should scroll? as you have mentioned you want  scrolling text not textView. or you want part of text i.e some string to scroll.

Comment: sorry, its multiple textviews. I want to show a number of notifications that moves from bottom to top or vice versa

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this example code below it will do a marquee like html

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mywidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="#ff4500"
    android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"/>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choice for that:

**1) Use Native way:** using thread, put 10 spaces before any text and in each second remove left side space and increase right space and so on, until it's limits. Hope you understood. **Predefined TextView's below properties also uses this method.**

**2) Use predefined control TextView with below properties:**

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have main layout as ScrollView ,Create vertical LinearLayout as child of ScrollView and create  (number of textview you required ) textViews inside LinearLayout.

*you should change **android:layout_height***
as per your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/activity_main"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:background="#FF4081"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="1st Line !" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="2nd line !"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="3rd line !" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```