# Marquee text in not working continuously

Tags: android

i have issue with marquee text. i have textView which is marquee continuously. it is working fine. but after several hours app getting stuck and text isn't marquee. Please help me with this

Comment: Check this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3598855/3946958

Comment: ok i wil try that bro