# title in toolbar is too big i want title to move right to left

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Toolbar title is too big whole title cant be seen.
Is it possible to move title right to left like **marque** in HTML?
it should look like animation I've seen much application with moving title. But I've no Idea how they did that.

```
toolbar.setTitle(""+Common.downloadsList.get(index).getName());
```

Comment: Have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working

Comment: it is in text view how can i use it in app bar title

Comment: Use like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/7666442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement like this.

These are the main properties to achieve marquee text.

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

**XML code:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

Your **Activity** should look like this.

```
Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
AppCompatTextView toolbar_title = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbar_title.setText(""+Common.downloadsList.get(index).getName());
}
```