# Android clipRect not clipping as expected

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to clip the string when it hits the icon.

[image]

This would mean that the string would be clipped when it hit `iconSize + iconMargin`.

This is the code I have in `onDraw`, which does that exactly:

```
canvas.save()
canvas.clipRect((itemIconSize + itemIconMargin).toInt(), 0, 0, 0)
canvas.drawText(
      item.title,
      item.rect.centerX() - (itemIconSize / 2 + itemIconMargin),
      item.rect.centerY() - textHeight, paintText
)
canvas.restore()
```

The problem is that the string doesn't clip and behaves like it is displayed in the image above.

How can I clip the string when it hits the icon?

Answer (score 0):

`canvas.clipRect` takes four parameter as input to represent a rectangle in canvas coordinates.

- left = X coordinate of rectangles left corner
- top = Y coordinate of rectangles top corner
- right = X coordinate of rectangles right corner
- bottom = Y coordinate of rectangles bottom corner

The rect in your example has 0 as top and bottom corner Y coordinate and this results in a rectangle with 0 height. So change your code to something like this:

```
canvas.clipRect((itemIconSize + itemIconMargin).toInt() //left: right side of icon
, 0 // top: top point of the view
, view.width // right: end of the View
, view.height // bottom: bottom of the View
)
```

Comment: That works! But now when I clip it, the animation I had stops, why is that?

Comment: Hmm Im not sure about that. Can you confirm its not working due to clipping related code?