# Marquee in various TextView at the same time?

Tags: android, layout, textview, marquee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make ellipsize=“marquee” always scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsize-marquee-always-scroll)

I have a dynamic layout wich has one to six TextViews. All the TextViews are created in the Activity (programatically) and all are created equally.

I want to marquee the text in the TextViews, but I don't know how to do it. Apparently, the TextView needs to be focused for the marquee works fine, but how i focus six TextViews at the same time? I think that's not possible, so, is there any workaround? Is it possible to get the marquee working without having the focus?

This is the code of the TextViews:

```
//TextView
TextView tvTitulo = new TextView(this);
tvTitulo.setText("Some loooooooooooooooooooooong text");
tvTitulo.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
//Marquee
tvTitulo.setSingleLine();
tvTitulo.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
tvTitulo.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
tvTitulo.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

If I remove the line `tvTitulo.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` the marquee is not working at all.
If I don't remove the line, only one of the TextViews is getting the marquee working.

Greetings

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/android-is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsizemarquee-always-scroll

Answer (score 3):

Make tour TextView Selected add this line of code

```
tvTitulo.setSelected(true);
```

now more than one TextView marquee will works.