# TextView Marquee not working

Tags: android, textview

I have tried to use marquee and its not working
here is my code, please let me know where im going wrong

```
<TextView
   android:text="lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00"
   android:id="@+id/TextView02"
   android:layout_width="200dip"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
   android:ellipsize="marquee"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:inputType="text"
   android:maxLines="1">
</TextView>
```

i am using android SDK 2.0.1

Comment: its working in Android sdk 1.5

Comment: @ Paresh Have you tested it on 2.0.1?

Comment: May be its late but it may help others.. you have to do it programatically TextView.setSelected(true);

Answer (score 327, accepted):

working now :)
Code attached below

```
<TextView
    android:text="START | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | END"
    android:id="@+id/MarqueeText" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
    android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
    android:paddingRight="15dip" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:freezesText="true">
```

**Edit (on behalf of Adil Hussain):**

`textView.setSelected(true)` needs to be set in code behind for this to work.

Comment: To add to hooraygradschool's comment: the value of `layout_width` and `layout_height` can be whatever you want it to be (doesn't have to be `fill_parent`), you can specify `android:singleLine="true"` instead of `android:lines="1"`, and `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` is not essential (text running fine for me without it).

Comment: For me "maxLines=1" was not enough. But "singleLine=true" made it working.

Comment: @WindRider in fact maxLines=1 does nothing - despite being the recommended replacement for the now deprecated singleLine=true.

Comment: android:singleLine="true" instead of maxline="1" made it worked for me. but is it possible to have marquee with two lines?

Comment: Suppose you have a custom background for the TextView with the selected state. This will always make your selected state background applied.

Answer (score 99):

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

are the only required attributes and scrolling even works with `layout_weight` defined with `layout_width=0dp`

here is some sample code:

```
<TextView 
            android:id="@+id/scroller"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Some veryyyyy long text with all the characters that cannot fit in screen, it so sad :( that I will not scroll"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

But what is most important is implicitely or explicitely `TextView` **should get selected**.

You can do this with:

```
TextView txtView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
txtView.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: Instead of setting TextView 'selected' as true programmatically, you can specify "android:focusable" and "android:focusableInTouchMode" as true in the xml layout file.

Comment: Just ran into a situation where TextView marquee animation was not working despite setting all the necessary xml attributes (`singleLine`, `ellipsize`, `marqueeRepeatLimit`, `focusable`, `focusableInTouchMode`) and calling `TextView.setSelected(true)` did the trick so big big thank you for pointing that out!!

Comment: Thank you, this post is more helpful than the selected answer.

Comment: agree with khendricks!

Comment: layout_width could be either fill_parent, match_parent or wrap_content all works I tested it. Required attributes definitely are the ones mentioned in this answer along with the textView.setSelected(true) is a MUST.

Comment: how to find some view and setSelected in Preferences? I want to make TextView in PreferencesActivity do marquee :S

Answer (score 25):

These attributes must be included in the `textview` tag in order to allow scrolling.

Everything else is optional.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

Comment: The attribute `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` is not essential for text scrolling (though you do need to set the TextView's width).  The following two attributes you should consider using: `android:singleLine="true"` and `android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"`.

Comment: Note that sometimes it is necessary to call `TextView.setSelected(true)` in code (despite setting all the necessary attributes) as per Shardul's answer so give that a try if marquee animation is not working.

Comment: android:focusableInTouchMode="true" not required

Answer (score 24):

I faced the same problem and this discussion helped me I just replace this line

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

with this line in xml

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

and it works
the line `txtView.setSelected(true);`
was also in my activity.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my time.

Comment: `android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated.

Comment: for work with `android:maxLines="1"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/46360549/5381331

Answer (score 18):

```
 <TextView
  android:ellipsize="marquee"
  android:singleLine="true"
  .../>
```

must call in code

```
textView.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: `android:singleLine` isn't needed

Comment: `singleLine=true` is the key here, if the number of lines is more then it won't work.

Answer (score 15):

I had gone through this situation where textview marquee was not working. However follow this and I am sure it will work. :)

```
<TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_marquee"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ellipsize="marquee"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
         android:freezesText="true"
         android:maxLines="1"
         android:scrollHorizontally="true"
         android:text="This is a sample code of marquee and it works"/>
```

and programmatically add these 2 lines...

```
tvMarquee.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
tvMarquee.setSelected(true);
```

tvMarquee.setSelected(true) is required incase if any one of the view is already focused and setSelected will make it work.
No need to use.

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

it is deprecated and above codes works.

Comment: How to change the speed of scrolling text?

Answer (score 14):

**Very Simple working code:**

For infinitely scrolling text

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_News_HeadLine"
            style="@style/black_extra_large_heading_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="-1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="HeadLine: Banglawash To be Continued" />
```

& you should must write from your activity

```
textView.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 11):

You must add the these attributes which is compulsary to marquee

```
 android:ellipsize="marquee"     
 android:focusable="true"    
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"     
 android:singleLine="true"     
 android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"     
 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

And also add this line of code in the activity class

```
textView.setSelected(true)
```

Answer (score 10):

I've encountered the same problem. Amith GC's answer(the first answer checked as accepted) is right, but sometimes textview.setSelected(true); doesn't work when the text view can't get the focus all the time. So, to ensure TextView Marquee working, I had to use a custom TextView.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if(focused)
            super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
        if(focused)
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isFocused() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then, you can use the custom TextView as the scrolling text view in your layout .xml file like this:

```
<com.example.myapplication.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvScrollingMessage"
            android:text="@string/scrolling_message_main_wish_list"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>
```

NOTE: in the above code snippet com.example.myapplication is an example package name and should be replaced by your own package name.

Hope this will help you. Cheers!

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: This is the only solution that works everywhere.

Answer (score 9):

Working Code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Some veryyyyy long text with all the characters that cannot fit in screen, it so sad :( that I will not scroll"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm working with minSDK=14 and was curious what set of these variations would work.  I ended up with:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:singleLine="true"
```

in addition to other formatting stuff.  I didn't need scrollHoriontally, focusable, or focusableInTouchMode.

This set did require a call to

```
setSelected(true)
```

What I find interesting is that singleLine has allegedly been deprecated, with a recommendation to replace it with maxLines = 1.  Except - when I do that, that change alone stops the text from scrolling.  One would hope that when singleLine eventually bites the dust, that all its current behavior will be triggered by maxLines...

Answer (score 5):

Just add those as said above:

```
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
```

AND!! you *must* use TextView.setSelected(true) inside your java code.

The reason for marquee not working with some of the guys in this article , If you have an input form with an EditText ( which is an input), The EditText will be the one with focus and selection by default in the form. Now, if you force it thru TextView.setSelected(true), TextView will eventually do marquee no matter what.

So the whole idea is to make the TextView widget focused and selected to make marquee work.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following line in your code:

```
TextView.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
package com.app.relativejavawindow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        final RelativeLayout relativeLayoutbotombar = new RelativeLayout(this);
        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setId(1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativlayparamter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativlaybottombar = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relativeLayoutbotombar.setLayoutParams(relativlaybottombar);


        textView.setText("Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long ");
        textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        textView.setSelected(true);
        textView.setSingleLine(true);


        relativeLayout.addView(relativeLayoutbotombar);
        relativeLayoutbotombar.addView(textView);
        //relativeLayoutbotombar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        setContentView(relativeLayout, relativlayparamter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

this code work properly but if ur screen size is not fill this text it will not move try to palcing white space end of text

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **marquee_forever** also work in case of **fixed width for TextView**. (e.g. android:layout_width="120dp")

**Must required attributes are:**

1. android:focusable="true"
2. android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
3. android:singleLine="true"    // if it's missing text appear in multiple line.

Working code:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/mediaTitleTV"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Try Marquee, it works with fixed size textview smoothly!" />
```

Comment: `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` is required too

Answer (score 2):

I have created a custom class **AlwaysMarqueTextView**

```
public class AlwaysMarqueeTextView extends TextView
{
    protected boolean a;

    public AlwaysMarqueeTextView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        a = false;
    }

    public AlwaysMarqueeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeset)
    {
        super(context, attributeset);
        a = false;
    }

    public AlwaysMarqueeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeset, int i)
    {
        super(context, attributeset, i);
        a = false;
    }

    public boolean isFocused()
    {
        return a || super.isFocused();
    }

    public void setAlwaysMarquee(boolean flag)
    {
        setSelected(flag);
        setSingleLine(flag);
        if(flag)
        setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        a = flag;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) 
    {
        if(focused)

            super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused)
    {
        if(focused)
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
    }
}
```

And you can startMarquee when desire.. like

```
//textView.setSelected(true); No need of Selection..
textview.setAlwaysMarquee(true);
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this but the text isn't marquee'ing. I've added it as a class, using it instead of the TextView, set the various standard marquee parameters on it and then called setAlwaysMarquee.

Comment: Figured it out. However there is a slight pause each time it cycles. Any idea how to make it constantly move round rather than have that slight pause.

Answer (score 2):

To have your own scroll speed and flexibility to customize marquee properties, use the following:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text" />
```

Within your activity:

```
private void setTranslation() {
        TranslateAnimation tanim = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 1.0f * screenWidth,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, -1.0f * screenWidth,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f);
        tanim.setDuration(1000);
        tanim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        tanim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        tanim.setRepeatMode(Animation.ABSOLUTE);

        textView.startAnimation(tanim);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put these parameters in your TextView. It works :)

```
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

`

Answer (score 0):

android:focusable="true" and android:focusableInTouchMode="true" are essential....

Because I tested all others without these lines and the result was no marquee. When I add these it started to marquee..

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers are identical,
but also notice that in some cases marquee will not work without specifying of width in dips for the container.
For instance if you use weight in parent container

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
```

marquee may not work.