# making a ticker in android

Tags: android

I have a list of 1000 quotes which i want to display in a textview which scrolls smoothly and continously. I have viewed this question [Horizontal scrolling text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862409/horizontal-scrolling-text-in-android)
which explains how to do this for a single line of code. After viewing another very similar question i realised that it is very difficult to caluclate the screen width and divide it by the speed for each stock as the stocks are of different lengths. Is there any new tutorials out there which explains how to achive this.([Simple Android Scrolling Text Ticker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735394/simple-android-scrolling-text-ticker)
 the author of this question seems to have given up and not used a ticker). Is there nothing starightforward to make a ticker in android.

The question bears a very close resemblence to the second question i have linked. But since a year has almost gone by i wanted to know if any new ways of implementing this is now available.