# text-sliding bar similar to news bar

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to develop something similar to a scrolling news bar which displays news on the bottom of the tv channel. It would look something like this

> ..em Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ips...

It updates with newer text everytime it moves from left to right with newer content. I was thinking in using a textview flipper but it just changes from 1 entire view to another. Is there any recommendation that could assist me?

Comment: Refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working You might be looking for the same. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView txt = new TextView(this);     
txt.setText(“This is moving text”);      
txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16);     
txt.setTextColor(Color.rgb(187, 88, 15));     
txt.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 0);     
txt.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);     
txt.setSingleLine();     
txt.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(10);     
txt.setFocusable(true);     
txt.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);     
txt.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);     
txt.requestFocus();     
txt.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(130, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
txt.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF,Typeface.BOLD);
```

Hope this helps.