# Limit the text in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a textview Which Contains some text changes dynamically within the UI like below

layout:

```
<TableRow android:weightSum="2" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/archive"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
                android:background="@drawable/archive" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_width="-200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/facebook" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="2dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titlename1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="@string/nowplaying"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titlename"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:maxEms="25"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="11dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="2dp" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/playbtn"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/play" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/pausebtn"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/pause" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mainlayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-203dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />
        </TableRow>
```

My Problem is that when i execute my Program,my layout output:

```
Imagebutton1     ImageButton2

NowPlaying:    SongDetails

Play/Pause      SeekBar
```

Problem is If my SongDetails text lenght Contains 2 or 3 lines My layout is getting Disturbed?Could any one Suggest?My Requirement is to limit the text like

**Song Detailssss etc......in a Same Row**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `android:singleLine="true"`, and `android:ellipsize="end"`. So You need to update TextView code as

```
<TextView
                .....
....
                android:ellipsize="end"
               android:singleLine="true" />
```

Refrences :

1. [android:singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine)
2. [android:ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize)

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

in your `textview`

also you can set [marquee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working).

Note that this marquee will work if your text line is longer then your screen size only.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting android:ellipsize paremeter to "end"

Like this

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting android:ellipsize paremeter to "end" if you want to trim the content at the end.

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove wrap_content. That should work(haven't tried it myself recently, but I used it a couple of months ago).

Otherwise, you could cut the text manually in Java, and cut it at the first newline found.