# Text Marquee is not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, textview

Please have a look at the following code

```
<TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView22"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textColor="#ffffff"
                 android:textSize="12sp"
                 android:text="@string/r_new_event"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView23"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Meeting with people i have never seen before in my entire life lol"
                 android:ellipsize="marquee"
                 android:maxLength="10"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                 android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                 android:textColor="#ffffff"
                 android:textSize="12sp"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</TableRow>
```

This attempt is to marquee the text if it is longer than 10 letters.  But unfortunately, this code is not working. I tried in moth emulator and Android phone. What is wrong here?

**Update**

Following is my new code, it is still not working

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Meeting with people i have never seen before in my entire life lol"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: I think you have to have the textview in focus for it to marquee as well

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working and http://developer-dot-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/marquee-effect-in-textview-tutorial.html

Comment: @androiduser: The amazing fact is, that is also not working!!!

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence: Have you tried my code?

Comment: Remove android:maxLength="10" and it will work.I tried it just now.

Comment: just write in onCreate yout_text_view.setSelected(true);

Comment: let me know is it working or not..? ,  it is working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code..

XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mywidget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textColor="#ff4500"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class TextViewMarquee extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv);  
        tv.setSelected(true);  // Set focus to the textview
    }
}
```

Comment: Only this code is not enough. The layout width MUST BE 0dp, in order to work in version 4

Answer (score 0):

Add these:

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
android:freezesText="true"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried, no good. Please have a look at the updated question

Comment: Check @DineshKumar's answer. You should add `setSelected(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your textView with below code

```
<TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView23"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Meeting with people i have never seen before in my entire life lol"
                 android:ellipsize="marquee"
                   android:lines="1"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                 android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                 android:textColor="#ffffff"
                 android:textSize="12sp"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                 android:focusable="true" 
                 android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
                 android:freezesText="true"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: i am using your given xml code and edit that code it is working

Answer (score 0):

use below custom TextView / onCreate just write your_textView.setSelected(true);

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
        Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    if (focused)
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
    if (focused)
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
}

@Override
public boolean isFocused() {
    return true;
}
```

}