# How to show floating lyrics and visualizer in widget?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, srt

I'm developing this Music Player app, where I need to show floating lyrics and visualizer in the widget. For lyrics, I'm getting `.srt` files from server, and for visualizer I want to use Android Default Visualizer?

Any suggestions will be a great help..

Comment: use marquee :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working

Comment: Yes, but how am I gonna sync the display marquee , with srt blocks?