# ellipsize="marquee" doesn't work in spinner

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner, marquee

I am using a simple spinner:

```
final SimpleCursorAdapter statusAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null,
new String[] { "_id" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);
statusAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
statuseSpinner.setAdapter(statusAdapter);
```

There is `android:ellipsize="marquee"` attribute in both `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` and `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`. But I don't see any marquee animation when text is long.

As I read in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working), I should call `setSelected(true)` in textView. So I extend a custom adapeter and here is `bindView` method:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view
        .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        textView.setSelected(true);
}
```

But It didn't solve the problem. So how can I have marquee with spinner?

Comment: why dont u use custom spinner item?

Comment: @d.i.v.a you mean that I should create a custom layout instead of using `android.R`? So what's the difference if I create a custom layout with a TextView containing ellipsize attribute?

Comment: becoz i m not 100% sure that android.R.layout...will contain ellipsize...

Comment: It contains, I checked it.

Comment: can u provide me link ?

Comment: I have no link. In eclipse IDE I can see source of `android.R.layout` files by holding `ctrl` and clicking on their name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62912/discussion-between-d-i-v-a-and-misagh-emamverdi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats true that  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item contains android:ellipsize="marquee"  [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml)
but there are other attributes also you need to define in android xml below id code snip :

row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[COMPLETE SOURCE CODE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwx47sxosv1cepf/Mtetno_NotifyMe.rar?dl=0)