# How to apply marquee to the android Text view

Tags: android, textview, marquee

How to apply marquee to the android Text view
My marquee was not working, Where i did my mistake here is my code please help me to solve this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" 
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:gravity="center">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="111dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/user_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/user_name_hint" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="570dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Login_title"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.71"
            android:text="@string/clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:text="@string/signin" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here this is my java code orshould i apply marquee tag dynamically :

```
package com.example.demo2c1testpanel;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbRequest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Loginpage extends Activity
{
    public static final int targetVendorID = 6790;      
    public static final int targetProductID = 29987;
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devicelist= null;
    public  UsbManager manager;
    public  UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection;
    public  UsbInterface usbInterfaceFound = null;
    public  UsbEndpoint endpointOut = null;
    public  UsbEndpoint endpointIn = null;
    public  UsbDevice usbdevice,device_details;

    Button clear,signin;
    EditText username,password;
    String i = "";
    Intent i2;
    String User_Name=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);

        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
        username.setSelection(0);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

        signin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_signin);
        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                {
                check_connection();
                }

            }       
            });

            }

    public void check_connection() 
    {

        int i,j;
        String as[];
        User_Name=username.getText().toString();

        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        i = deviceList.size();
        if(i==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this,"Device Not Connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        as = new String[i];
        deviceList.keySet().toArray(as);
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            device_details = (UsbDevice)deviceList.get(as[j]);
            if((device_details.getVendorId()==targetVendorID) && (device_details.getProductId()==targetProductID))
            {
                Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this,"Device Connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(User_Name.toLowerCase().equals("medequip") && password.getText().toString().equals("medequip"))
                {
                    i2 = new Intent(Loginpage.this,TestsPage.class);
                    startActivity(i2);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this,"Invalid username and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }


            }

}
}
```

Comment: Just append you TITLE with "Android" and Copy/Paste in Google. You will get first link as i answered. Dont be Lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Try out like this:

```
<TextView
    android:text="START | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | END"
    android:id="@+id/MarqueeText" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
    android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
    android:paddingRight="15dip" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:freezesText="true">
```

Reference from : [TextView Marquee not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3333855/1318946)

Comment: i copied and pasted your answer atmy project but it is howing some error like this  Exception raised during rendering: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Comment: Exception raised during rendering: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Comment: My whole xml was posted above