# Auto scroll textView without three dot

Tags: android, textview

I am using this code to do auto scroll when length of testView is exceed to screen width:-

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tViewWork"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Name of work: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#dedfdc"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I want to scroll the character without three dot. The above code scrolling the character but at the end three dot is displaying.

[image]

Comment: remove the line`android:singleLine="true"` in your xml sheet

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add below attributes to your `TextView`. You are missing `android:ellipsize="marquee"` attribute in your xml

```
   android:ellipsize="marquee"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
   android:singleLine="true"
```

And also set selected true for you `TextView` in java code

```
  TextView tViewWork = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tViewWork);
  tViewWork.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code :

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/fact" android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:text="Loading... More text to see if it spans or not and want more"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:duplicateParentState="true">
<requestFocus android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:duplicateParentState="true" />
```

Refer : [TextView Marquee not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working)

Answer (score -1):

remove
    android:singleLine="true"  it  will automatically takes as much width and height as it wants