# android automatic horizontal scrolling TextView in a TableRow in a TableLayout?

Tags: java, android, scroll, textview

Hoping someone can shed some light.

I've currently got a **ScrollView(vert)**, to which a **TableLayout** gets programmatically added to it, to said TableLayout a TableRow is added, to which a TextView along with other similar views are added.

The problem is that this text can be longer than the screen and I need a way to make the text in the TextView scroll automatically unlimited amount of times.

Note there can be quite a few of these table rows added to the one table layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the horizontal scroll like marquee then below is the code

```
<TextView
    android:text="START | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | END"
    android:id="@+id/MarqueeText" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
    android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
    android:paddingRight="15dip" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:freezesText="true">
```

if you want the custom one [extended marquee effect](http://www.ivity.asia/2010/12/01/extended-marquee-in-android/). Hope this is useful for you.

Comment: I've seen this posted a few times, the problem is that the TextViews are created programmatically. Is there a way to set a custom view if I were to create a TextView XML?

Comment: fallow this link here is complete code with custom TextView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working