# Android Marquee Wait duration

Tags: android, textview, wait, marquee

How to make a Marquee TextView wait for a specific time until it starts to scroll horizontally?
Because when I open an Activity it starts straight to scroll. So you have to wait until its back on startposition to read it.

Answer (score 4):

In the XML I simply added `TextView` like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!, Hello World!, Hello World!, Hello World!, Hello World!, Hello World!, Hello World!, Hello World!"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Then in code (in Activity, but can be anywhere):

```
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setSingleLine(false);
    textView.setMaxLines(1);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setSingleLine(true);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working) in order to activate textview marquee you have to add this :

```
tv.setSelected(true);
```

As you want to start the marquee with a delay you have to put this inside your run() like this

```
tv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv.setSelected(true);          
            }
        }, 1000);
```

this will delay it

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
             android:id="@+id/testing"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:ellipsize="marquee"
             android:focusable="true"
             android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="Some veryyyyy long text with all the characters that cannot fit in screen, it so sad :( that I will not scroll"
             android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
/>
```

Then, in activity just set using setSelection to true. I already tested it and its working

```
testing.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                testing.setMaxLines(1);
                testing.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
                testing.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(10000);
                testing.setSelected(true);
            }
        }, 3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is delay the focus of textview so that it starts it marquee after a certain period of time. The following code starts rolling the marquee after 2 seconds.

```
yourTextview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                yourTextview.setSelected(true);          
            }
        }, 2000);
```

**P.S :** You first need to post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I created a marquee_forever. i could not find any information how to do that so I had nothing so far. But thanks! I will try it out!

Comment: this does not change anything

Comment: To set Marquee Forever use: <br>testing.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);