# Marquee using maxLines

Tags: android, textview, ellipsis

How can I have a marquee using MaxLines instead of SingleLine ?

This is my TextView :

```
<TextView
    android:text="bla bla bla bla bla bla"
    android:id="@+id/MarqueeText" 
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:freezesText="true">
```

After in my code.java I `setSelected` my `TextView` :

```
TextView txtView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.MarqueeText);
txtView.setSelected(true);
```

The problem is `android:singleLine` is deprecated so I have to use `android:maxLines` instead but the marquee don't work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this :

```
android:maxLength = "10"
```

OR

After setting `android:maxLines="1"`, you have to set your `inputType` too. So, set your `android:inputType="text"` and that should do the trick.

Comment: we can't set inputType for a TextView

Comment: Why not? see this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Answer (score 4):

In XML

```
<TextView
    android:text="11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
    android:id="@+id/text_marquee"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    />
```

In Java

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_marquee)).setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_marquee)).setSelected(true);
```