# how can make name of the application movable in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar

my Application name is too big ...it got truncate in the end of the toolbar ..how can I make title movable

I will not disclose my app name just take an example

here is the ss:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MF6G.png)

I have only declared the name in strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">here is my title is too big to display in toolbar</string>
 </resources>
```

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working

Comment: @TalhaAhmed text is not moving still it is truncate

Comment: try to create text view inside toolbar and then try