# marquee_forever not working on Android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0, marquee

I have a `TextView` in my app that is defined with `marquee_forever`:

```
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/networkNameTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/wefiPrimaryColor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

It works perfectly on Xiaomi Android 8.1 but on a Galaxy Note Android 10 it doesn't work.
Instead I get `android:ellipsize`.

Is there a new parameter required or is this a problem with Android 10 or Galaxy Note?

Comment: Not an OS version thing i guess . have you tried some of tricks mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working)?

Comment: I tried the ones that involve changes to the XML. I'll try the rest and see what happens.

Comment: Seems that adding tvMarquee.setSelected(true); does the trick. NO idea why.

Comment: That's why I said trick in first place . Because I am not sure either have to look at the source code . Pls mark it as duplicate since your problem is solved .

Comment: Not often you get to vote to close your open question :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TextView Marquee not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do that. If `TextView` fill whole width you need to add these lines of code

```
<TextView
    .
    .
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    />
```

also do not forget to set selected for `TexrtView` as below

```
textview.setSelected(true);
```

and If `TextView` does not fill width the only thing is to call this method and pass `TextView` to it.

```
    fun addMarquee(textView: TextView) {
    textView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val pixels = textView.measuredWidth - 1
            val params = textView.layoutParams
            params.width = pixels
            textView.layoutParams = params
            textView.isSelected = true
            textView.ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE
            textView.isSingleLine = true
            textView.marqueeRepeatLimit = -1
            textView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    })
}
```

**NOTE:** this method only work when textView width is `wrap_content`.