# Show lengthy text in TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I create a TextView by using java code.I need to create textView with the width 50;If the textView has a lengthy text how to display the full text.Is there any marquee in android?If it exist how to apply it in textView???

Note:

i use more no of textview's and i add all textviews in to the table layout.I create all textView at runtime only(After read the data from the db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have "lengthy text ", use height as wrap_content and it will break the line, and adjust the height as per content

Comment: i use more no of textview's and i add all textviews in the table layout.I create all textView at runtime only(After read the data from the db)

Comment: This link http://bear-polka.blogspot.com/2009/03/marquee-feature-of-textview-in-android.html            has some marquee example, i have not tried it personally, may be you can try it.  Also see this post        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsizemarquee-always-scroll

Answer (score 2):

I fixed by using

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

hope this works for you too

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are provisions for marquee text .Check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt)

Use this

```
    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtArticleTitle);
    tt.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    tt.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(1);
```

Also check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMarqueeRepeatLimit(int) 
& you are done!