# Running string in Android

Tags: android, textview

I'm not sure, if "running string" the right name.

I try to explain, what I mean.

I have a TextView in my Layout and want to have text there, which runs from rigth to left, again, and again, and again.

I thougt, I just should enable marquee for that, but the text stays instead of running :(

Here is my TextView-Code:

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/text_ticker" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:background="@color/grey0" 
 android:textColor="@color/black" 
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
 android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
 android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
 android:padding="10dp" 
 android:ellipsize="marquee"      
 android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
 android:scrollHorizontally="true">
</TextView>
```

Thank you,

Mur

Comment: Is the text longer then the screen can show? Otherwise it probably won't scroll.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make ellipsize="marquee" always scroll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsizemarquee-always-scroll)

Comment: Yes, it is ... as I said, I haven't found right word for search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ellipsize marquee scrolling will only scroll when the textView gains focus.

Edit:
[Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/android-is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsizemarquee-always-scroll)

Comment: and how to get scrolling without getting focus?

Comment: In the topic you've sent me I found also ticker.SetSelected(true), that is much easier than the answer marked as solution :) Thank you

Comment: Is there the possibility, to change the way of repeats. Now it's not really fluent at the end of displaying. I've tried also suggestion with animation. The only way now is to add many spaces at the begin and the end of my tickertext

Comment: You would have to define a custom animation instead of using marquee if you want to change the way it scrolls.

Comment: I would know what else to suggest, try a different animation? I also dont like the way marquee scrolling works honestly. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.