# Android Marquee

Tags: android, marquee

Is there any working example for Marquee in android? I went through some sites, but that examples are not working.

Thank you for the answers.. But the following code is not working anyway. I am using Android 2.2.

```
       <TextView    
             android:singleLine="true"  
             android:ellipsize="marquee" 
             android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
             android:text="Marquee.."/>
```

Answer (score 32):

it's easy to do via XML. Use the following settings:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:focusable="false"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

If your TextView is within a RelativeLayout, the width or height will have to be static (i.e. 32dp). If you need dynamic, place the TextView in another View within the RelativeLayout.

In onCreate(), you need to make the TextView selected:

```
myTextView.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: myTextView.setSelected(true); is MUST!.. otherwise it is just not working...

Answer (score 2):

The code lines you were missing are :

```
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
```

In the text field try this text as it is a long text.

```
android:text="This is a very long text which is not fitting in the screen so it needs to be marqueed."
```

Check my complete code and step by step process [here](http://yhisham.blogspot.in/2012/08/android-how-to-make-marquee-ticker.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to do this in java..

```
tv.setSelected(true);
```

and the xml will be

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:focusable="false"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use android:ellipsize="marquee"

```
 <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"   
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:text="Simple application marquee sample..."/>
```

Keeo Text to large enough to let it perform marquee effect..

Answer (score 0):

You can set **`ellipsize=marquee`** and **`marqueeRepeatLimit`** attribute:

For example: I have set for the TextView:

```
 android:ellipsize="marquee"
 android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
```

You can refer this SO Question for the best information: [Is there a way to make ellipsize="marquee" always scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsizemarquee-always-scroll)