# Dynamically change titlebar height in android

Tags: android, titlebar

I'm using a custom titlebar created for my own use in the app i'm making, containing the title and some buttons. However occasionally I get titles that are slightly too long for the titlebar, where the titles are out of my control.

Currently setting the titlebar's height through "android:windowTitleSize="70dp"" in the titlebar's theme, but is there a way to dynamically change it if I can detect that the incoming title is too long and falls over into two lines?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution for this either.. but you could try android:ellipsize="end".
This way if the text will flow out of the TextView's bounds, the text will be cut of at the end and "..." will be added to the text.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) is also the documentation.

Comment: I would have done so if it were any other text other than the title. Having a "..." in any titlebar makes me feel weird, like having a book title too long for the book.

Comment: you can use marquee also.. here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344349/android-marquee but I don't recomend using two lines text on the app's title bar either

Comment: It is a move i'd take if im desperate enough; however then if i get a one line title instead of a multi line one i'd have too much space.
Does not look good either.