# Text animation in Android using translate

Tags: android, textview, translate-animation

I want to animate the text of the textview in android, i have a textview in which the text exceeds the width of the textview. I am using translate animation horizontally. It is animating the whole text view control. Using marquee property in text view does the job for me but it is quiet slow in compare to what i want to achieve. I need to know is there any way that i can animate the text of the textview (not the whole control) smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want a text "marquee" for when there is too much text for the TextView. If that is the case, trying the following links:

[Android Marquee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344349/android-marquee)

[TextView Marquee not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working)

Comment: Actually the issue is that i have applied the "marquee" but the text is dynamic, i want the text to scroll horizontally even if the text is less the screen width or text view width "something link news bar at the bottom". Marquee is very slow in speed and on wider screens it looks more slow

Comment: I guess you could check the length of the string to be displayed and if it is too short, repeat the string until it is long enough to scroll.