# Vertical Maquee TextView

Tags: android, animation

From the prevois post, [Is there a way to make ellipsize=“marquee” always scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/android-is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsizemarquee-always-scroll) I have create a vertical maquee textview. But my question is how can I hold the animation around 5 sec when it moving to a point and than resume and finish the animation.

For example:

```
mAnimation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 20f, -20f);
mAnimation2.setDuration(5000);
mAnimation2.setStartOffset(5000); 
mAnimation2.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); tv.setAnimation(mAnimation2);
```

I have define the above animation and set it to TextView. How can I stop the animation 5 sec when the textview was at coordinate (0,0) and than continues the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take this MarqueeView implementation and customize it up to your desire: http://b.ivity.asia/2010/12/01/extended-marquee-in-android/

Comment: Great!!! ur code is work!!! thanks u save my time. but may I ask some question? the MarqueeView is it need to focus then it only will restart the animation? i.e: the animation only will run again when I touch the screen. Do you have and idea to solve it? mean it will keep running itself. Thanks and sorry about my bad english..

Comment: Sure, you can do that easily. Probably by adding a onClickListener, and call the startAnimation block there. Be sure to remove the automatic startAnimation within the MarqueeView.

Comment: Do you mean call the startAnimation block from onClickListener? I think my question is no clear. let me explain again. I need the animation auto run forever. but now in my app it didn't run the "mMoveText1TextIn" after "mMoveText1TextOut" finish. when I just simple touch the screen again, then "mMoveText1TextIn" only will start porperly. How can make the "mMoveText1TextIn" run again without touch the screen? should I override the onFocusChanged? Thanks and sorry about my bad english.

Comment: You might try that. But sounds a little complicated. Do you have the entire source code somewhere?

Comment: I'm just using your source code. But I just have do some edit. I need the TextView moving from bottom to top. so I set "mMoveText1TextIn = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -20)" and "mMoveText1TextOut = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 20, 0)". other I just follow your code. And I have notice if I comment the "mTextField1.setOnClickListener(l);", then the animation wont restart anymore.Thanks

Comment: Tried for hours to make it scroll vertically, gave up.

Comment: Maybe @WynixToo could share his solution. Else you could open a github repo and let us take a look?