# Automatic Scroll Text Within TextView Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-scrollview, autoscroll

I am creating application which is having textview with lots of text and want to perform automatic vertical scrolling till the text ends. But i am not getting the way to perform automatic scroll.

I have reffred https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo project. 
But could not get success with this code..

Here is my XML Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/vertical_scrollview_id"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1.0"   
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:scrollbars="none"
 >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/vertical_outer_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
   >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lyricView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="16"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"            
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="200dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/showLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-150dp"
        android:background="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>   
</ScrollView>
```

Pleaze give me some idea. Thanx in advance.
My simple scrolling functionality works well. But i want to perform automatic vertical scroll..

Comment: But i want automatic vertical scroll. If you have any idea then send me code block.

Comment: how automatically u want to perform can you plj elaborate this.

Comment: @Dipu - I have edited my que. Do u have any idea?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4546882/1777090 for automatic scrolling

Comment: I think this will help you [Click here](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition/blob/master/ignition-core/ignition-core-lib/src/com/github/ignition/core/widgets/ScrollingTextView.java)

Answer (score 2):

Try putting text view alone inside scrollview as:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content_scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_margin="7dip"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lyricView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="16"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"            
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="200dp" />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have content that fits your screen which doesn't need scrollview, it doesn't appear. But when your content exceeds the screen, then the scrollview comes into picture. You have to change the height attribute of textview to `wrap_content` to make it automatically increase its height as per content.

Try this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e6e6fa"
    android:padding="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/vertical_outer_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
   >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lyricView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="16"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"            
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="200dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/showLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-150dp"
        android:background="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>   
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by automatic scroll?