# Scroll a text automatically on horizontal

Tags: android, xml, textview, scrollview

[image]

I want to scroll a text automatically in horizontal way. I tried the method below, but the text was not scrolling.

```
   <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_1"
    android:textColor="#cc0000"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   />
```

So please tell me how to scroll a text and if there is any need to add some code in the class file also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i put a listview in above textview so the textview is not scrolling. so itried this one

```
set listview focusable is false

listview.setfocusable(false);
```

then it works the text was scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

your TextView don´t scroll because their with must be fill_parent, and the other thing is that the textview must be selected (not pressed) to scroll.

Comment: thanks for giving replay. i replaced width with fill_parent but it didin't scrolling

Comment: alraedy i set the text in class file

Comment: TextView wont scroll if isn´t selected, Selected mode don´t work in Touch screen. Check if selecting the TextView with the keyboard pad get the textview scrolls. Also, check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsize-marquee-always-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Also, beside what Franco told you, you have set `android:ellipsize="marquee"`(that truncate the text to fit on that single line you have set), so probably that mix up with the scrolling you set by `android:scrollHorizontally="true"`
My suggestion is to try to remove the ellipsize property.

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion. i removed the ellipsize property but it didin't scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="John Jonathan Samuwell Abbruzzi"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="50sp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```