# How to flush the shown text in marquee?

Tags: android

I have created a marquee text using TextView in android. My requirement is to flush the shown text in the marquee and append new text to it. How to flush the shown text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hanry You are right but i think it will marquee only if it gains focus.. i had this problem earlier.. what i did is replaced the textview with webview and used  marquee tag to make the text scroll.

Edit : Response to sangita

```
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(26);
        webview.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Black);
        webview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //DO actions here
            }
        });
        String content = "MARQUEE TEST";

        String summary = "<html><FONT color='#fdb728' FACE='courier'><marquee behavior='scroll' direction='left' scrollamount=10>"
                + content + "</marquee></FONT></html>";
        webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: This is scrolling continuously. I need to scroll once.

Comment: add loop="1" inside the marquee tag

Comment: Is it possible to append text to it?

Comment: modifying variable "content" will naturally append or modify displaying content

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> setMarqueeRepeatLimit (int marqueeLimit)

set to 1 and add new text by appending new one DO this for each time you append new text and set to -1 when finished.

Comment: @sangita You can refer to:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsize-marquee-always-scroll)