# Android: I have some problems with the marquee-feature of TextViews

Tags: android, textview

I have some problems with the marquee-feature of TextViews. I want to have a scrolling newsticker like this:

News 1 -- News 2 -- News 3

When a new news enters it must append with previous one as below,

News 1 -- News 2 -- News 3  -- news 4

How can i implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tell me where did you want the marquee effect to be in your activity or web view?

Comment: now i used a text view with horizontal scrolling. The problem is when a new content (news) arrives i just append it with previous contents. Doing so scrolling restart from the first news itself. I just want the scrolling to continue with new news appended at its end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsize-marquee-always-scroll).

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

Take a webview in xml.
from code you declare the webview.
In that webview..

WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String summary = ""+your data+"";

mWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");

it will help you.

Comment: how can you say that he want the effect in web view it is also possible in activities too?

Comment: @Karthik Marquee is welknown fetures as we use in HTML. generally it is use on web. and android gives this facility of webview and I think it suited better thats why i suggested. And This Marquee i had used in my development.