# Set textview fading in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, textview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've just tried to implement the fade effect for `TextView` in Android 4.0.3; however, it doesn't work.

```
fadingEdge="horizontal"
singleLine="true"
ellipsize="marquee"
```

This code works perfectly for 2.3.7 and below, but not working for 4.0.3.
I'm wondering why is that so? and how to make fade effect for `TextView`?

My question is the same as this one: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/97131b20de8b2ebd , but no answer yet.

Comment: Use setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit late, but that may help people who have the same question.

I have had this problem on different phones, and it could come from that :

- on Android 4.0.x, it seems that the TextView have to be focusable, otherwise fade effect won't work. So try adding this :

  android:focusable="true" 
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
- if that does not work, you could try android:lines="1", but i think that android:singleLine="true", which is deprecated, works better
- sometimes, you need to programmatically call setSelected(true) on the textView to get the fade effect. Please check this link : [Is there a way to make ellipsize="marquee" always scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsize-marquee-always-scroll)

Comment: if you set `android:focusableInTouchMode` then users must touch to receive the focus and the fading effect happens. however, I want it to display with fading effect normally as in GB 2.3.x

Comment: did you try the different combinations of android:focusable and android:focusableInTouchMode ? If it still does not work, I'm afraid the only solution is to programmatically call setSelected() on your textView

Comment: i know that if set `android:focusableInTouchMode`, it will work as long as user touch the `TextView` in order to receive focus and it will transform into fading effect. what I mean is the natural state of `TextView` should be like that, no touch required.

Comment: As I tested this on a Galaxy Nexus, I have had no problem with android:focusableInTouchMode="true". With touch mode activated, well,  I guess you will need to try some programmatic solution from the link above.

Comment: To get it to work on a Nexus running Android 4.4 I needed to set ellipsize="marquee", marqueeRepeatLimit="0" and fadingEdge="horizontal" in the xml and use setSelected(true) programmatically. Without setting marqueeRepeatLimit="0" I was getting automatically scrolling text which is not what I wanted.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I looked and I looked (through several git repos) but I can't for the life of me find this chunk of code. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As of API level 14 `fadingEdge` is deprecated and ignored so in order to make fading edge work on Android 4.0.3 you must use `requiresFadingEdge` instead.

Comment: requiresFadingEdge also not working. Any suggestion !