# android ics fading edges don't work

Tags: android, layout

somehow fading edges seems not to work for android ics (android 4+) for own views. If I test this layout on a lower android version it paints the fading edge but not on android 4.1.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" <-- does not make any change
    android:focusable="true"           <--
/>
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"Using fading edges may introduce noticeable performance degradations and should be used only when required by the application's visual design. To request fading edges with API level 14 and above, use the `android:requiresFadingEdge` attribute instead"

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge

Comment: Furthermore: http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/22/why-is-my-list-black-an-android-optimization/

Answer (score 4):

You can try some ideas from answer in my question post: [Set textview fading in Android 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307644/set-textview-fading-in-android-4-0-3)

However, it seems like the fading edge won't work on 4.x somehow. The reason why? I don't know.

Comment: Fading edges don't work in ICS and beyond because they were deprecated and are now ignored. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge

Comment: @Anderson ffleandro posted it as an answer and has plenty of upvotes to go with it. No sense in posting another answer just to make a rep grab.  My comment will suffice as it does the job in delivering the information which is the point of this site in the first place. =)