# Implement shortcut text format like in application launcher

Tags: android, text, android-launcher

I want to format my text for shortcuts as same as shortcut texts in application launcher. Too long text will be cut and its tail will be faded away. Is there anybody know how to do that?

[image]

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Add `fadingEdge` to your `TextView` definition

```
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
```

However this method is deprecated for performance degradation issues and should be used only when required by the application's visual design.

To request fading edges with `API level 14` and above, use the

`android:requiresFadingEdge` attribute

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge)

Comment: Thanks for your tip. However, it doesn't work at my side. I found that fadingEdge does not work in ICS anymore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816849/android-ics-fading-edges-dont-work

Comment: ya it is ignored from `Android 4.x`. From `4.x` onwards you have to use `android:requiresFadingEdge` attribute.

Comment: requiresFadingEdge also doesn't work. Does it work at your side?