# Android: TextView is not scrolling Automatically

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView with following attributes :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/appheader" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Actually the TextView scrolls ONLY when I click the TextView. But I want to scroll it automatically when I launch the Activity. How can I do this ?

Comment: "scroll it automatically" are you referring to marquee here?

Comment: Could you define "scroll" more? Because if you want it to scroll through the text that is in the TextView, you're gonna have a problem, since you've put it on singleLine="true".

Comment: add in ur activity in which u have used textview TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.appheader); tv.setSelected(true);

Comment: have u check ans given by me it works try that

Comment: Why the text won't scroll if we set singleLine="true". Its working for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="very long text to srollll dkfjadkfjkldjfkjdkghjhtudhfjhdjfkdfkadjsajekdfjak" 
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

By-default `TextView` marquee effect works when it get focus. To make an automatic marquee effect you need to extend `TextView` class. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsize-marquee-always-scroll) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

`set android:scrollHorizontally="true"` for that textview.

Also set the following two properties:

```
text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

text.setSelected(true);
```