# ScrollHorizontally multiple TextView at the same time

Tags: android, xml, scroll, textview

I searched for a solution online but can't seem to find one.
I have a `LinearLayout` with 2 `TextView` that contain text that does not fit and should scroll within the `TextView`. Using the typical solution only one scrolls. I want both of them to scroll.
**My xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pl_name1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="A very long piece of text that it is not going to fit the screen"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pl_name2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Another very long piece of text that it is not going to fit the screen"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image: Layout]

How can I achieve what I want, or what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to scroll it automatically by marquee or by user on scroll?

Comment: In the image above I want both text to scroll since they don't fit the view on a single line

Comment: By marquee, or by the user? You have marquee directives in there

Comment: by marquee of course.

Comment: Found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2504840/1369566