# How to set marquee in infinite repeat limit in main activity?

Tags: android

What value should I put inside the parameter to make the marquee repeat limit to forever?

```
holder.hTextTitle.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
holder.hTextTitle.setMarqueeRepeatLimit();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set infinite marquee programmatically use:

```
TextView txt = new TextView(this);
txt.setText("This is the infinite marquee");
txt.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
txt.setSingleLine(true);
txt.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
txt.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: nice answer, but how did you know the value for marquee_forever is -1? i want to discover that by myself

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_test);
    textView .setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    textView .setSingleLine(true);
    textView .setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
    textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    textView.setFocusable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        tv.setText("Your text…");
        tv.setSelected(true);
        tv.setSingleLine(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
```

Also, do look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsize-marquee-always-scroll).

Comment: OP is asking to do this programmatically, and not through XML way.