# Android Button Marquee

Tags: android, button, marquee

Attempting to scroll some text horizontally on a button, not bothered if it has focus or not. Just want to scroll the text. Right now, got the button to appear, but only text I see is "My button.."

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="150dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My button with a long text for marquee as a example source code"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="1"/>
```

Comment: Have a look at this question, everything should apply to Button as well. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1827751/2001247

Comment: Thanks for this - can get textview to scroll but not button.

Answer (score 3):

In the activity (.java file) you have to add the lines:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

        btnMarquee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
        btnMarquee.setSelected(true);
```