# Android Studio: Making Action Bar text scrollable

Tags: java, android

[Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HefnM.png)

I am using the following code to display the text stored in the array:

```
AppUtil.popMessage(this, "Streaming song: " + selectedSong.getTitle());
```

But the full text is not shown because of the limited space.

How do I add a marquee scrolling to the Action Bar?

Comment: You need to create your own custom class extending the `Toolbar` class

Comment: android:ellipsize="marquee" but only works when your TextView has focus.Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsize-marquee-always-scroll

Answer (score 1):

you need to create custom toolbar layout like bellow:

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:title="Title">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_title"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="title"
         android:textSize="20dp"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:maxLines="1"
         android:ellipsize="marquee"
         android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
         android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
         android:scrollHorizontally="true"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```